# Extend filename with wildcard in for loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to delete the files in a directory/sub dirs that were used to create videofile.mp4. Problem is that although all files begin with the same filename, some have had the file name appended during the creation process so %%~na does not catch all filenames. Example of files in folder is videofile.mp4 videofile.ac3 videofile.m2v videofile-02.ac3. Using echo in place of delete for starters:

```
for /r %%a in ("*.mp4") do (echo "%%~dpna.m2v" "%%~dpna.ac3")
```

This skips over videofile-02.ac3. Adding * as wildcard within the do parenthesis results in literal interpretation of *, no matter where I've tried to insert *. Is there a way to extend the filename part of %%a with a wildcard?

Comment: please use proper code formatting, by selecting the code and clicking on the `{}` symbol next time

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purposes, use `dir` instead of `echo` as `dir` treats wildcard `*` character like `del`:

```
for /r %%a in ("*.mp4") do (
   dir /B /S "%%~dpna*.m2v" 2>NUL | findstr /I "%~dpna"
   dir /B /S "%%~dpna*.ac3" 2>NUL | findstr /I "%~dpna"
)
```

In above code snippet:

- `dir /B /S` displays files with (fully) qualified paths in bare format (no heading information or summary);
- `2>NUL` suppresses `File Not Found` message;
- `| findstr /I "%~dpna"` suppresses displaying files in subdirectories.

As soon as (no sooner than) debugged:

```
for /r %%a in ("*.mp4") do (
   del /F /Q "%%~dpna*.m2v" 2>NUL
   del /F /Q "%%~dpna*.ac3" 2>NUL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried:

```
for /r %%a in ("*.mp4") do (echo "%%~dpna.m2v" "%%~dpna*.ac3")
```

and it worked for me (If I didn't misunderstand your intention).

In another way: Wouldn't it be enough with:

```
for /r %%a in ("*.mp4") do (del /s %%~na*.*)
```